# Error al enviar Newsletter por mailing

Tags: html, css, html-correo

Buenos días señores, quería ver si podían sacarme de un aprieto, tengo un cliente que me encargó un newsletter con sectores interactivos linkeados a sus redes y web, sucede que se lo armé integramente en html, al subirlo al servidor se lo puede visualizar perfectamente, pero al enviarlo en su gestor de mailing el newsletter se desarma todo. El gestor de mailing se lo provee su hosting, y desde el servicio técnico del mismo le indicaron que es muy normal que las planillas tengan que adaptarse a varios "User Agents" y que el CSS tenga que tener alternativas basadas en quién los abre. El problema está en que no se como adaptar el código a diferentes User Agents. Adjunto una captura de como queda el newsletter al recibirlo con GMAIL.

[image: Captura de Newsletter]

Agradecería si alguno me puede dar una mano con esto, si es necesario subo el código, mi cliente ya me está volviendo loco. Gracias desde ya

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que se ve en la imagen de la pregunta estás usando un "image map". De acuerdo a [Image Map Support in HTML Email](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/image-map-support-in-html-email) estos son soportados por la mayoría de los clientes de correo, sin embargo tienen limitaciones, como por ejemplo, los clientes de dispositivos móviles escalan las imágenes lo cual "romperá" el mapa de imagen.

Cabe mencionar que en Gmail podemos usar `<style>`, estilos en línea y un subconjunto de CSS. La lista completa de los selectores soportados por Gmail está en https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/reference/supported_css

En la [respuesta aceptada](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8243403/1595451) a [Gmail image map - only the last area works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8243291/1595451) sugieren

- Siempre usar tablas
- Nunca usar `<p>`
- Siempre poner `display:block` en las imágenes para evitar espacios entre imágenes

También valdría la pena que consultaras

https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/